# unit test filling form on git commit

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-commit

I want to have the ability to fill a form (a couple of questions) for every git-commit I do. Something more than a comment. I mean that every time I git-commit, a little unit-test form will pop-up with a couple of built-in questions and the developer will write what was unit-tested before this feature/change commit.

Usually we do commit from command line or from visual studio (we write in C#).

Does anyone know a nice automatic solution for that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Git Commit Message Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873577/custom-git-commit-message-template)

Answer (score 0):

One command line option would be to edit your `~/.gitconfig` file and specify a template file for commit messages:

```
[commit]
template = ~/.committmpl
```

Then, edit `~/.committmpl` and add your content, e.g.

```
Please describe what was unit tested:
```

Now, every time someone commits, the above template would populate the commit message.  If you wanted to enforce that something is written, perhaps an issue number, etc., you could setup a hook which checks the commit message.

Comment: thanks. I was not familiar with it. Besides that method - is there any way to call an executable, for example, to run every time a commit is done ?

Comment: @user1902346 I'm not familiar with it.  There is probably a way to do the equivalent of what I wrote above from an IDE (e.g. Visual Studio).

Comment: Thanks, I will try. I saw that there is a way that I will write my own exe and in the .git\hooks\pre-commit to call this exe. When I am doing a pre-commit file there does it override an existing one ? If so how can I make sure to add my call on pre-commit and then it will continue as before I added the pre-commit ?