# How to creat a commit template in git

Tags: git

I was trying to create a commit template, but when I do a commit I get this message

**fatal: could not read 'templates/commit-template.txt': No such file or directory**

I follow the next steps to create the commit template:

- I create a new folder named templates, inside git folder
- I create an archive commit-template.txt inside de folder templates

In gitbash I typed the following:

```
$ git config --global commit.template templates/commit-template.txt
```

I reviewed the config and I saw this, it seems ok :(

```js
commit.template=templates/commit-template.txt
core.repositoryformatversion=0
```

But when I have tried to do a commit I received the message I wrote before (**fatal: could not read 'templates/commit-template.txt': No such file or directory**)

I have read about commit template in a book and I followed the instrucción, but I don´t know what am I doing wrong. I found some informaticon on the links below(and other more), but I am still lost. Could someone help me please.

[Custom Git Commit Message Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873577/custom-git-commit-message-template)

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/5-useful-tips-for-a-better-commit-message

Comment: It's relative to the repository root, not the .git directory. If you put it in `.git` you need `git config --global commit.template .git/templates/commit-template.txt`.

Comment: @Schwern thank you very much. I don't know why I couldn't figure out something simple, the only I had to write was to full path of my commit-template.txt I feel fool –

Comment: We've all banged our heads against the wall on something like this.